# Unsupported python project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio-2017

I had a VS2015 solution with a C# and python project in it. Now I upgraded visual studio to "2017 community preview" version.

If I try to open the solution **from Visual Studio** by clicking on File/Open/Project... it pops up the following error message:
[Unsupported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMjLv.png). After that VS cannot open the python project in the solution (it sais "incompatible" next to the project file). It can open the C# projects.

But if I simply **double-click on the *.sln** file, VS automatically starts up and offers the following one-way upgrade: [One-way upgrade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAd7i.png). After doing the upgrade it can open the python project as well and everything works properly.

Even though after making the one-way upgrade the first type of opening (from VS) **still does not work**. Opening by clicking on the solution file still works.

Thanks for any help how I can resolve this issue.

Comment: What details are displayed when you click on "More information" in the dialog boxes? Also, isn't support for Python a VS add-on? If that's the case, you may have to find and install a version of that which is compatible with the upgraded version of VS.

Comment: "More information" on both dialog boxes redirects to the same, follwing page: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/porting/port-migrate-and-upgrade-visual-studio-projects) on which the "py" term is not even mentioned...Looks like it is only me who ever created a python project in visual studio :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG, I got the answer...

I had both **VS 2017 community** and **VS 2017 community preview** installed on my computer. (That is because obvously I installed the simple community version at first, and only installed the other when I realized it does not support python.) I did not either think that preview version will not overwrite the existing one but will make a new install.

So when I click on the sln file it opens up with the preview version of VS, but the shortcut in my start menu refers to the normal version... :S :D

Answer (score 2):

Python tools for visual studio 2017 is only available for the preview version. It will be added soon to the non-preview version.
source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2017/03/07/python-support-in-vs2017/